# What does "they are the most eager to return after a retreat" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am not sure what "*they are the most eager to return after a retreat*" means in the context of the following hadith:

> Al-Mustawrid reported: He said in front of Amr ibn al-‘As that he
> heard the Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, say,
> “The Hour will be established while the Romans are the majority of
> people.” Amr said, “Be careful what you say.” He said, “I have said
> what I heard from the Messenger of Allah.” Amr said, “If the Prophet
> said that, indeed, there are four good qualities in them: they are the
> most forbearing of people in tribulation, they are the quickest to
> recover after a calamity, **they are the most eager to return after a
> retreat**, and they are good to the poor, the orphan, and the
> vulnerable. Their fifth quality is good and beautiful: they are the
> best at stopping the oppression of their kings.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2898
>
> Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Muslim

Does it mean that when faced with a superior opponent, they back down but will be eager to once again return to the battle field to fight against him?

Comment: *Retreat* could have been used in the sense of *going away from your home to a secluded, quiet place*. And then, after it, you *return* back home.

Comment: This is not about learning English, but about interpreting a religious text, so I'm closing it to new answers.

Answer (score 1):

Note, first of all, that these are the comments of Amr, not statements of the Prophet (SAW).

The phrase "they are the most eager to return after a retreat" or "أَوْشَكُهُمْ كَرَّةً بَعْدَ فَرَّةٍ" in Arabic mean that they are eager to return to the fight after a defeat.

Meaning, they do not let defeat hold them back from returning to another battle or trying again.

The example of this in the Prophet's time was the prophecy in Surah Rum:

> The Romans have been defeated
>
> In the nearest land. But they, after their defeat, will overcome.
>
> Within three to nine years. To Allah belongs the command before and after. [...] (30:2-4)